# Was Taiwan free of new COVID-19 cases for 30 days up to 12th May, 2020?

Tags: covid-19, taiwan

- Anadolu Agency, a Turkish news agency [reported  on 6th May](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/asia-pacific/-taiwan-s-sars-experience-helped-it-beat-covid-19-/1830547):

  > It has been 24 days since the last case of local transmission of COVID-19 was reported in Taiwan.
- Agon Hare is a musician who runs a Facebook page [Project Nightfall](https://www.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=1305415602988734&id=500689923461310&extid=AwRjaXALIJs3JjB2&d=null&vh=e) with 1.6 Million followers. On May 11th he posted a video claiming Taiwan was the first country to "win" against COVID-19. In particular, he claimed that Taiwan:

  > in the past 22 days haven't had any locally transmitted cases.
- Taiwan News, [reported on May 12th](https://www.taiwannews.com.tw/en/news/3932422)

  > Taiwan has now extended its streak of no new local infections to 30 days.
- Focus Taiwan [reported on 12th May](https://focustaiwan.tw/society/202005120009) (Hat tip: @Fizz)

  > No new COVID-19 cases in Taiwan for five straight days

Has Taiwan remained free of new (locally-transmitted) COVID-19 cases for 30 days leading up to 12th May 2020?

Comment: What does "beat" mean? Stop it spreading? Cure it? Find a vaccine? I checked one of your links, and it just talks about halting transmission.

Comment: @hdhondt - see my edit

Comment: Add a concrete claim you're challenging e.g. "It has been 24 days since the last case of local transmission of COVID-19 was reported in Taiwan." And note that was on May 6. They actually had more cases since then, although not many https://focustaiwan.tw/society/202005120009

Comment: @Fizz see my edit

Comment: Ok, but I don't see how this is implausible or how we could verify it beyond government sources. New Zealand has claimed the same (albeit for not as long) https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-52436658 (NZ update [here](https://www.newsroom.co.nz/2020/05/11/1101216/covid-19-in-nz-the-numbers)) Neither country had a big local outbreak.